# LeetCode 39. Combination Sum - How to avoid duplicates

Tags: python, combinations, depth-first-search, backtracking

I am doing  [leetcode 39. Combination Sum.](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/):

> Given an array of **distinct** integers `candidates` and a `target` integer target, return *a list of all unique combinations of* `candidates` *where the chosen numbers sum to* `target`. You may return the combinations in **any order**.
>
> The **same** number may be chosen from `candidates` an **unlimited number of times**. Two combinations are unique if the frequency of at least one of the chosen numbers is different.
>
> It is **guaranteed** that the number of unique combinations that sum up to `target` is less than `150` combinations for the given input.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - `1 <= candidates.length <= 30`
> - `1 <= candidates[i] <= 200`
> - All elements of `candidates` are **distinct**.
> - `1 <= target <= 500`

I was able to write the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        output = []
        
        def backtrack(currNbr, comb):
            if currNbr == 0:
                output.append(comb.copy())
                return
            elif currNbr < 0:
                return
            
            for nbr in candidates:
                comb.append(nbr)
                currNbr = currNbr - nbr
                backtrack(currNbr, comb)
                comb.pop()
                currNbr = currNbr + nbr
                
        backtrack(target, comb = [])  
        
        return output
```

However, I cannot make it in sort to avoid duplicates. I have seen some solutions online but they all seem to use an index `i`. Can anyone please explain to me, how to change my code to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is common to make use of the index `i`. This is because once you iterate to the next `nbr` of `combinations`, nowhere in the deeper recursion, should an entry be selected from `combinations` that comes *before* the one selected here.

You can do this without `i`, and instead pass a shortened copy of `combinations`, which will only have those entries which are still allowed to be selected.

There are several ways to do this. One should take care of correctly iterating over a list when you also want to make it shorter. Also, `pop()` is more efficient than `pop(0)`. So I have opted to use `reversed` to iterate in reversed order:

```
        def backtrack(candidates, currNbr, comb):   # Extra parameter
            if currNbr == 0:
                output.append(comb.copy())
                return
            elif currNbr < 0:
                return
            
            for nbr in reversed(candidates):  #  Reversed iteration 
                comb.append(nbr)
                backtrack(candidates[:], currNbr - nbr, comb)  # Pass a copy
                comb.pop()
                candidates.pop()  # The discarded element should not be used 
                
        backtrack(candidates, target, comb = [])  #  Extra argument
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the insightful answer. I understand better now.